# turkish/hungrairan/ polish letters not executing properly

Tags: php

I'm a bit of a novice here so my apologies if I didnt derive this answer from earlier posts I read.

I put together a file in php. Everything works when the URL to the php file is executed, except some of the Polish and Turkish characters come up as question marks (in utf8 and unicode) and simply disappear and turn into latin letters in anicode.

i edited both in wordpad and notepad.

How can I fix this problem, please?

thanks.

```
function array_utf8_encode($dat)
{
if (is_string($dat))
    return utf8_encode($dat);
if (!is_array($dat))
    return $dat;
$ret = array();
foreach ($dat as $i => $d)
    $ret[$i] = array_utf8_encode($d);
return $ret;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Return the array back to Qualtrics
print  json_encode(array_utf8_encode($returnarray));
?>
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidelines there to refine your question with additional information, such as code and error message to describe your programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need to add the json_encode JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option:

```
print  json_encode(array_utf8_encode($returnarray), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Other json_encode options are at: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php